# is there a way to check if the scanf is empty? The scanf is appending to a double array

Tags: c

`double array[40]; int var = 0; while (scanf("%lf", &array[var])== 1){     var++;`
sometimes the double array is left empty by the users that are inputing data. how can i check if the array isnt empty. if it is empty i will add a print statement. I cant add 0 to the whole list or else it can mess up some results. that the user enters and null values only work in char.

`$echo -n ' ' | ./test`

`your statement is empty`

Comment: When its empty, `var` will be 0.

Comment: i added an if statement after the while loop, if var == 0 and nothing happened

Comment: You should post a [mcve]. Otherwise we have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: I was given a method to put random numbers inside it

Comment: In order to stop the input you need to break using `ctrl+d` or have to check for input array limit. [DEMO](https://onlinegdb.com/0klrpJNZr)